# CSS wildcard hover working on codepen but not locally or on server

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to use the following CSS and the hover effect doesn't work if I'm viewing the HTML/CSS locally via liveserver in VSCode, or simply opening the HTML file from the file explorer. It also doesn't work if I upload the HTML/CSS files to a server. However, if I place the exact HTML and CSS in CodePen, the hover effect works just fine.

When I'm viewing it locally or on a server (where the hover doesn't work) and I toggle the hover state on in Chrome DevTools, it acts like there is no CSS for the hover state, but if I toggle the Focus state on, it indeed works as expected and applies the CSS.

Why would this hover effect work in CodePen - here - https://codepen.io/stemlund/pen/BadGJZy, but not locally or when uploaded to a server?

```css
.dot-indicators>* {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: red;
}

.dot-indicators>*:hover,
.dot-indicators>*:focus {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="dot-indicators flex">
  <button aria-selected="true"><span class="sr-only">Slide title</span></button>
  <button aria-selected="false"><span class="sr-only">Slide title</span></button>
  <button aria-selected="false"><span class="sr-only">Slide title</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: On the page where it doesn't work, is your CSS linked, or in the same page?

Comment: The same code is placed on a web server here - https://stephenemlund.com/hover-help/ - the CSS is linked correctly. The hover just doesn't work like it does on codepen

Comment: don't forget the doctype declaration, you HTML code is missing

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Ah I didn't catch that. I added the doctype and now the code works as expected. So odd that no doctype breaks random CSS declarations. I was following an online course and the course code also had no doctype!

Thanks for the help!